# Integration in statistical mechanics

Tags: calculus

How to integrate
$$ \int \frac{h k}{e^{(hk-\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{u})/(k_BT)-1}}d\mathbf{k}$$
where $h,k_B,T$ are constants and $k=|\mathbf{k}|$. The integration is taken over $k_x,k_y,k_z \in(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: Hmmm, your integrand looks wrong. Should the $-1$ outside the exponent. i.e. the denominator is $e^{(\cdots)} - 1$ instead of $e^{(\cdots - 1)}$?

Answer (score 1):

Make the change of variables $\cos\theta = x$ where ${\bf k} \cdot {\bf u} = uk \cos \theta$, then the integral will be:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{2\pi k^3 dx dk}{e^{\beta k(h-ux)} -1}
\end{equation}
Where $\beta = 1/k_B T$ and the $\phi$ integration gives the $2 \pi$. Perform first the $k$ integration by changing variable to $w = k \beta (h-ux)$ that is

\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{1} \beta^4 (h-ux)^4 dx \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{w^3 dw}{e^{w}-1}
\end{equation}
The integral over $w$ is known (it can be found, e.g. in Feynman's lectures) to be $\frac{\pi^4}{15}$
and the last integral over $x$ is elementary, and produces

\begin{equation}
\frac{\beta^4}{5u^2}([u+h]^5 + [u-h]^5)\cdot \frac{\pi^4}{15}
\end{equation}